# Exporting Aesthetic Text Plots in R

Tags: r, reporting, analysis, summary

I'm very new to R and am currently trying to replicate some summary tables I currently create on Excel as part of a monthly sales report.

I am using two sets of data, one named `Sales` and one named `Cancellations`. I am using the `aggregate` command to summarise these however I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a package or command which will allow me to make the output more aesthetic (ie, change fonts, add borders, etc...)?
2. How do I add a grand total row?
3. How do I save summary tables like this so they can be exported and viewed as pdf or excel file?
4. How do I plot both the sale summary and cancellation summary on the same page?

### The code I've been using is below.

```
sales.summary <- aggregate(cbind(x = sales$RRP, x = sales$GWP, x = sales$Margin, by = list(sales$Channel), fun = SUM)
print(sales.summary)

cancellations.summary <- aggregate(cbind(x = cancellations$RRP, x = cancellations$GWP, x = cancellations$Margin, by = list(cancellations$Channel), fun = SUM)
print(cancellations.summary)
```

The end goal here is to create one sheet with both tables presented cleanly and professionally for viewing by shareholders.

I have attached an example of the output I currently create with Excel (all values have been fabricated, of course). I am hoping to achieve something similar through the use of R script only.[image]

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Dan.

Comment: What — of the numerous "table" formatting pkgs on CRAN — have you tried (with code examples) that has not worked? If only SO allowed LMGTFY links.